# How to compare acidity in the following aniline derivatives?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: made using https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/sketcher/]

Let the simplest one be a), ortho be b), meta be c) and para be d).
I have confusion between ortho and meta. How to compare their acidity?

Comment: Acidity or basicity?

Comment: The ortho is tricky, the rest is covered by Hammet relationship, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the case of ortho and meta in which you have confusion:

The acidity of aniline will increase if there is a electron donating group in the compound to stabilise the conjugate positive acid formed.

Since OMe is shows +R and -I effect, it is a net electron donating group as +R effect generally dominates over -I.So in case of ortho it is able to show electron donating nature due to +R effect which makes it more basic than the meta isomer which shows electron withdrawing effect due to only -I effect as +R effect will not affect from meta position.

Comment: I just got more confused. Can you please help me compare the basicity? Should not ortho be the most basic out of the four due to distance factor?

Comment: Distance factor plays role only in I effect not in R effect.Para is the strongest although both o and  p show +R because  the ortho since located closer to nh2 has more - I effect which withdraws more electron and hence stabilises the conjugate base lesser than para which has very kess - I effect due to distance factor.

Comment: Oh. I am new here. Done!

Answer (score 0):

According to [source](http://sites.chem.colostate.edu/diverdi/all_courses/CRC%20reference%20data/dissociation%20constants%20of%20organic%20acids%20and%20bases.pdf) the pKa values (of the conjugate acid) are:

```
compound            °C    pKa
Aniline             25    4.87
2-Methoxyaniline    25    4.53
3-Methoxyaniline    25    4.20
4-Methoxyaniline    25    5.36
```